# is it possible to infer the type of a type-parameter?

Tags: typescript, generics

so, In my typescript having the following enums:

```
enum TOKEN { OMG = 'OMG', ZRX = 'ZRX', ... }
enum CONTRACT_ADDRESS { OMG = '0x123...', ZRX = '0x3333.....' ... }
enum PRECISIONS = { OMG = 18, ZRX = 5, ... }
```

I used them in a generic class that looks like:

```
class ERC20Tx<T extends TOKEN, P extends PRECISIONS, A extends CONTRACT_ADDRESS>{ ... }
```

and then, for naming purpose, I added:

```
class OMG extends ERC20Tx<TOKEN.OMG, PRECISIONS.OMG, CONTRACT_ADDRESS.OMG> {}
class ZRX extends ERC20Tx<TOKEN.ZRX, PRECISIONS.ZRX, CONTRACT_ADDRESS.ZRX> {}
```

lastly, I have class whose task is to convert ETHTx, into one of the ERC20 above.

```
 class ETH2ERC20<E extends ERC20<T, P, A>, T extends TOKEN, P extends PRECISIONS, A extends CONTRACT_ADDRESS> { ... }
```

finally, my question is, is it possible to simplify the type of ETH2ERC20, because I'd prefer to call them like:

```
 const omgStream = new ETH2ERC20<OMG>({ ... });
 const zrxStream = new ETH2ERC20<ZRX>({ ... });
```

instead of:

```
 const omgStream = new ETHERC20<OMG, TOKEN.OMG, PRECISION.OMG, CONTRACT_ADDRESS.OMG>(); // ....
```

is it possible?, since OMG/ZRX/... would already contain the information what is T, P, A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly possible as long as your classes are [structurally](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) dependent on the types `T`, `P`, `A`, etc.  (For example, the classes could have properties of types `T`, `P`, and `A`.)  If you don't do that, the compiler will [be unable to infer the type parameters from your classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot---).

Anyway, let's look at your types.  The first simplification I'd suggest is just to use a single type parameter `K` corresponding to the keys of the three `enum` objects you've got.  Since those are all the same keys, and since it doesn't look like you are mixing-and-matching types (e.g., you would not do `class OMX extends ERC20Tx<TOKEN.OMG, PRECISIONS.OMG, CONTRACT_ADDRESS.ZRX> {}`), the extra type parameters are redundant:

```
class ERC20TxSimpler<K extends keyof typeof TOKEN>{
  k!: K;
  t!: (typeof TOKEN)[K];
  p!: (typeof PRECISIONS)[K];
  a!: (typeof CONTRACT_ADDRESS)[K];
}
class OMGSimpler extends ERC20TxSimpler<'OMG'> { }
class ZRXSimpler extends ERC20TxSimpler<'ZRX'> { }
```

Please note that I have created properties `t`, `p`, and `a` in `ERC20TxSimpler<K>` of the appropriate types corresponding to your old `T`, `P`, and `A` type parameters.  I've also made a `k` property whose type is `K`.  This is not strictly necessary as long as you have some other solid structural dependence on these types, but I will use these properties in what's to come.

The second simplification is to use the compiler's ability to infer and or [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) types to allow you to leave off the redundant type parameters in your `ETH2ERC20` class:

```
class ETH2ERC20Simpler<E extends ERC20TxSimpler<keyof typeof TOKEN>> {
  e!: E;
  t!: E['t'];
  p!: E['p'];
  a!: E['a'];
}
```

Note that this class also has properties, showing how you can figure out the types corresponding to your old type parameters.  The type of `ETH2ERC20Simpler<E>.p`, for example, is `E['p']`, meaning it looks up the `p` property in whatever you pass as `E`.  For example:

```
declare const eth2erc20omg: ETH2ERC20Simpler<OMGSimpler>;
eth2erc20omg.e; //OMGSimpler
eth2erc20omg.a; //CONTACT_ADDRESS.OMG
eth2erc20omg.p; //PRECISIONS.OMG
eth2erc20omg.t; //TOKEN.OMG
```

Looking up properties isn't the only way to pull types out of other types.  In general, as long as the structural dependency is straightforward enough, you can use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to pull out these types:

```
type KfromE<E> = [E] extends [ERC20TxSimpler<infer K>] ? K : never;
class ETH2ERC20Simpler<E extends ERC20TxSimpler<keyof typeof TOKEN>> {      
  e!: E;
  k!: KfromE<E>;
  t!: (typeof TOKEN)[KfromE<E>];
  p!: (typeof PRECISIONS)[KfromE<E>];
  a!: (typeof CONTRACT_ADDRESS)[KfromE<E>];
}
```

This has the same effect as the previous code but it relies on `infer` in conditional types.  Either should work.  I prefer lookups myself since they are not relying on compiler "magic" as much, but it's up to you.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the `infer` keyword to do this:

```
type InferToken<E> = E extends ERC20Tx<infer G, any, any> ? G : never;
type InferPrecision<E> = E extends ERC20Tx<any, infer G, any> ? G : never;
type InferAddress<E> = E extends ERC20Tx<any, any, infer G> ? G : never;

class ETH2ERC20<E extends ERC20Tx<TOKEN, PRECISIONS, CONTRACT_ADDRESS>, T = InferToken<E>, P = InferPrecision<E>, A = InferAddress<E>> { }

// Has type: ETH2ERC20<ERC20Tx<TOKEN.OMG, PRECISIONS.OMG, CONTRACT_ADDRESS.OMG>, TOKEN.OMG, PRECISIONS.OMG, CONTRACT_ADDRESS.OMG>
const a = new ETH2ERC20<ERC20Tx<TOKEN.OMG, PRECISIONS.OMG, CONTRACT_ADDRESS.OMG>>();

// or

const b = new ETH2ERC20<OMG>();
```